# Hierarchical Query with clause "START WITH" not work when use IN subquery as condition when using JdbcTemplate

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have query to find any member of team that below the group that lead by one upper level group of target employee, and test at DBeaver using query like below

```
WITH HIERARCHICAL_TB AS (
   SELECT 
      LEVEL as "XLEVEL"
      , t.EMP_ID as "EMP_ID"
      , t.NAME
      , t.JOB_POS_ID as "JOB_CD"
      , t.TEAM_ID
      , t.TEAM_PARENT_ID
      , 'TEAM_TREE' as "FOUND_AT"
      , PRIOR t.EMP_ID as "PRIOR_EMP_ID
      , PRIOR t.TEAM_ID as "PRIOR_TEAM_ID
      , PRIOR t.TEAM_PARENT_ID as "PRIOR_TEAM_PARENT_ID
   FROM 
      TB_EMPLOYEE t
      START WITH
         t.TEAM_PARENT_ID IN (
            SELECT 
               b.TEAM_PARENT_ID 
            FROM 
               TB_EMPLOYEE b 
            WHERE 
               b.EMP_ID IN (:TARGET_EMP)
         )
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR TEAM_ID = TEAM_PARENT_ID
         AND PRIOR EMP_ID <> EMP_ID
   )
SELECT 
   count(*)
FROM
   SELECT
      ht.XLEVEL
      , ht.EMP_ID
      , ht.NAME
      , ht.JOB_CD
      , ht.PRIOR_EMP_ID as "LEAD_EMP_ID"
   FROM
      HIERARCHICAL_TB ht
   WHERE
      ht.NAME like (':SEARCH' || '%')
```

this query work fine when run at DBeaver with correct amount number as result but...
when I use same query in code that using JdbcTemplate the result is zero.

but when I replace subquery with the static value like this

```
 WITH HIERARCHICAL_TB AS (
   SELECT 
      LEVEL as "XLEVEL"
      , t.EMP_ID as "EMP_ID"
      , t.NAME
      , t.JOB_POS_ID as "JOB_CD"
      , t.TEAM_ID
      , t.TEAM_PARENT_ID
      , 'TEAM_TREE' as "FOUND_AT"
      , PRIOR t.EMP_ID as "PRIOR_EMP_ID
      , PRIOR t.TEAM_ID as "PRIOR_TEAM_ID
      , PRIOR t.TEAM_PARENT_ID as "PRIOR_TEAM_PARENT_ID
   FROM 
      TB_EMPLOYEE t
      START WITH
         t.TEAM_PARENT_ID IN ('123456','345678')
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR TEAM_ID = TEAM_PARENT_ID
         AND PRIOR EMP_ID <> EMP_ID
   )
SELECT 
   count(*)
FROM
   SELECT
      ht.XLEVEL
      , ht.EMP_ID
      , ht.NAME
      , ht.JOB_CD
      , ht.PRIOR_EMP_ID as "LEAD_EMP_ID"
   FROM
      HIERARCHICAL_TB ht
   WHERE
      ht.NAME like (':SEARCH' || '%')
```

the second query got same result from DBerver and JdbcTemplate.

**the problem is:** why the first example query got difference result between **DBeaver** and  **JdbcTemplate** because the real query is more complex than these examples and I would like to use statement that can proof result from query tool before put it in to the code.

I use **ojdbc8.jar** as jdbc driver, it same as I use at **DBeaver (v6.3.0)**
and my project using **spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.2.2.RELEASE**

Comment: How are you supplying the bind variable values, for both queries and clients? I'd guess you're providing `target_emp` as a single string containing comma-delimited values - rather than a collection of individual strings?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank for asking, about variable `target_emp` I bind with single string but it just single emp_id no comma,  After you ask I also try bind it with List<String> but it still not work.

(debug log of JdbcTemplate show it turn from `b.EMP_ID in (:TARGET_EMP)` to `b.EMP_ID IN (?,?)` already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this query (as @AlexPoole make an observation)

```
SELECT 
   b.TEAM_PARENT_ID 
FROM 
   TB_EMPLOYEE b 
WHERE 
   b.EMP_ID IN (:TARGET_EMP)
```

the cause of problem is **b.EMP_ID** in table **TB_EMPLOYEE** contain white space, and got no result at JdbcTemplate but at DBeaver have result (I still don't understand why DBeaver got result), so I fix the query by turn `b.EMP_ID IN (:TARGET_EMP)` to be `trim(b.EMP_ID IN (:TARGET_EMP)`.

Thank you for all help.